# Fill matrix with values from other, smaller matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A`:

```
A = [-10 10];
```

And I'd like to create `B` like this:

```
[ -10 10
  -10 10
  -10 10
  -10 10
  .
  .
  -10 10 ]
```

with `d` rows.

I tried:

```
B(1:d)=A(:);
```

to fill rows from 1 to `d`  with A and a few other combinations, but I can't make it work. How can I achive this?

Comment: use the [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function

Comment: Also, consider skipping creating `B`. Depending on what you want to do with `B`, you may find you can do it with the original `A`, which is smaller. [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) may be handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many options, the simplest is to use the built in [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function:

```
repmat(A, n, 1)
```

Or you could use linear algebra:

```
ones(n,1)*A
```

Or you can use indexing:

```
A([ones(n,1), ones(n,1)*2])
```

Or as Luis Mendo points out, you might not even need to replicate it depending on your end goal as linear algebra or `bsxfun` might prove more efficient solutions.